# What would be the best workflow in Git considering the scenario below?

Tags: git

I have three branches. Master is the production's branch. Staging for testing and Dev for development. How do I merge only specif commits into master from staging branch? I don't always need to merge all differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a specific commit, the easiest approach would be to cherry-pick it:

```
$ git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```